# Is there a way to display balloon tooltips in crystal reports or SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, report

I have a report to build that has many different fields showing various results.
As these numbers are not intuitive, I need some sort of mechanism to display a balloon tooltip when the user hovers over or clicks on a number.

I am open to either Crystal reports or SSRS. I will just be limited to the free editions that come with visual studio 2008.

Any help or advice is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SSRS, most controls have [ToolTips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152802(SQL.90).aspx)

For example, the [textbox properties tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187583(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to "Format" these tool tips.Rather than just passing a string can I format it as HTML for example to highlight a title and then underline a couple of words?

Comment: Maybe try creating a mini-report in the tool tip itself.... <div><strong>TITLE!!!</strong> and more text and whatever and an image or whatever </div>   I can't test it though - no ssrs....

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports also supports tool-tip text.  Right click the field, select Format Field..., then the Common tab.  Enter a static value in the 'tool tip text' field or click the button to the right of the field and enter a conditional formula that will calculate the value.